# Eclipse Helios Ant Editor giving errors/warnings with Ant 1.8.1

Tags: ant, eclipse-3.6

I upgraded my OS Ant version to 1.8.1 (I use Gentoo Linux if that's important).  Previously I was using the OS's install of Ant 1.7.1 from within Eclipse Helios by changing the Ant Runtime to point to my Ant installation.  However after upgrading to Ant 1.8.1 I'm getting errors/warnings in the Ant editor when using 1.8 features.

For example if I try to import from a JAR via the  tag Eclipse gives me a warning saying that  doesn't support the  tag.  However the build file runs with no errors (using macrodefs from the imported file) from both within Eclipse and on the command line.

Therefore I know that Ant is working properly, but I don't know why the Ant Editor is reporting problems.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the ANT support in Eclipse Helios being based on ANT 1.6.1.

More info in the release notes:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_3.6.html#I-Platform-Ant

It seems Eclipse Foundation doesn't have a lot of priority on upgrading/updating the ant related tooling.